# Datatype of columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I created a Pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv method. When I check datatype of the dataframe columns using df.dtypes. I see datatype as either float64 or object.

I need to split datatype between int, decimal, string, date (yyyy-mm-dd format only), datatime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format only), time (hh:mm:ss format only).

I have huge number of files and do not have expected datatype list with me for each column. I need to derive this in the code.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has  `dtype` and `parse_dates` parameters?

Comment: @Nick I do not know in advance which columns are character versus dates etc. I need to decide that by looking at data.

Comment: for datetime you can use the parse_dates and infer_datetime_format parameters of read_csv

Comment: *I need to decide that by looking at data*, then load it and look at it. I mean for datetime, you have specific formats, you can use `.str.match` on the patterns to decide which column is which. Then there is `pd.to_numeric` to convert stuff to numbers, but then `read_csv` already does most of this conversion. If `read_csv` fails to recognize a number (int, float) column, then maybe it shouldn't be one.